# Simple communication in a LAN

Tags: .net, client-server, .net-4.5, communication

We made one application (we will call it App_A) that is installed on many PCs in a local network. This PCs do not communicate between each other (at least not through App_A), they only use same database server (SQL Server) to read / save data. This local network can be domain network, but also can be configured as a simple workgroup. I need to make some kind of signalling software (App_B), which will at some point (business rule) tell all running instances of App_A to shutdown / update / whatever. The ones that were not running should be signaled as soon as they start.

Communication is done automatically, without the user interaction. At some point App_B (which is running on only one PC) signals all instances of App_A in a local network to do something, and that is all.

Any ideas about what kind of solutions are there for this scenario? Is there some functionality I can already use (built into windows), or I need to make this from the ground up, and what kind of architecture would be most suitable for this1 (ex service, app, some kind of internal windows messaging, etc).

Comment: I would suggest you use udp broadcasting to signal out to all the pcs in your network (255.255.255.255).  You can also use udp broadcasting each time a new app starts, basically the new app instance will upd broadcast out (255.255.255.255) to tell the server (wherever it is on your network) that it (the new app instance) has just come alive and what its address is - and then the server can upd or tcp back to that specific address with what it wants it to do.

Comment: @Rob does that mean that I need to use one port for each client that I am communicating to?

Comment: If you do a broadcast to 255.255.255.255 the message goes out to all machines on your network, each machine already has its own port address so you only need to use the unique port address if you want to communicate specifically to one machine

Comment: @Rob I need to send signal to all machines in network that have this software installed, so that they should install it immediately. I do not need any other kind of communication, except to tell them to install update immediately. Does that mean that I need to open 100 ports for 100 PCs?

Comment: You just need to open the same (one) upd port on each of the listening machines, and then broadcast to it.

Comment: @Rob Can you please give some link where it is explain how this works, how to send broadcasting messages?

Comment: There are many examples on codeproject.com